# How to overwrite multiple line in rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to print status on ongoing process something like this:

```
|Label-1    |Label-2    |Label-3
|Data-1     |Data-2     |Data-3
|Data-1     |Data-2     |Data-3
|Data-1     |Data-2     |Data-3
```

With following code:

```
    println!("|{0:<25} | {1:<1} | {2:<10}", "URL Path", "Status Code", "Version");
    println!("{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10?}", resp.request_url, resp.status_code, resp.version);
    unsafe {
        if (FOUND.len() != 0) {
            for elem in FOUND.iter() {
                println!("\n\n{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10?}", elem.request_url, elem.status_code, elem.version);
            }
        }
        if (resp.status_code == 200) {
            FOUND.push(resp)
        }
    }
    stdout().execute(cursor::MoveUp(3));
    stdout().execute(terminal::Clear(terminal::ClearType::FromCursorDown));
```

The string of the rows have to be overwritten with new string. If it were one line, I could do `print!("\r{} | {} | {}",data1,data2,data3)` but since it's multiline the carriage return messes.

PS: Any example would be appreciated

Comment: Carriage return can only go back to the beginning of the current line. Anything more advanced will need more knowledge about your terminal emulator; you could for example use a library like `ncurses` for this.

Comment: @Thomas yes I have tried `crossterm` cargo in rust. As I understood, `terminal::ClearType::FromCursorDown` should clean everything from cursor to end. So my code becomes `stdout().execute(cursor::MoveUp(3));` `stdout().execute(terminal::Clear(terminal::ClearType::FromCursorDown));`. But it's only messing up like carriage return

Comment: [indicatif](https://github.com/console-rs/indicatif) may be of help

Comment: Provide a complete example of the crossterm code you tried, please.

Comment: @PitaJ updated the post, again any example would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, but holding a locked `stdout` worked for me:

```rust
use std::io::{stdout, Write};
use crossterm::{
    cursor, terminal, Result, ExecutableCommand
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut stdout = stdout(); // lock stdout and use the same locked instance throughout

    writeln!(stdout, "|{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10}", "URL Path", "Status Code", "Version")?;
    writeln!(stdout, "|{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10}", "https://google.com", 200, 9)?;
    writeln!(stdout, "|{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10}", "https://yahoo.com", 200, 15)?;

    // wait 2 seconds before replacing lines
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(2));

    stdout.execute(cursor::MoveUp(2))?;
    stdout.execute(terminal::Clear(terminal::ClearType::FromCursorDown))?;
    writeln!(stdout, "|{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10}", "https://bing.com", 200, 3)?;
    writeln!(stdout, "|{0:<25} | {1:<11} | {2:<10}", "https://duckduckgo.com", 200, 1)?;

    Ok(())
}
```